# In Rudin's PMA, is exercise 2.29 correct as written?

Tags: real-analysis

In exercise of 2.29 of Rudin's PMA, we are asked:

"Prove that every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$  is the union of an at most countable collection of open disjoint **segments**"

In definition 2.17, Rudin defines the *segment* $(a, b)$ to the set of all real numbers $x$ such that $a < x < b$.

Question: How can $\mathbb{R}$ itself be a union of at most countable collection of open disjoint segments? It seems to me that is impossible according to this definition of *segment*.

Comment: The statement as give is obviously false.  A singleton set is not the union of disjoint open intervals.  It is true however, that every *open* subset is such a union.

Comment: @saulspatz Forgot to include "open subset."  How is $\mathbb{R}$ the countable union of open disjoint segments?

Comment: What you have given is definition of segment $(a,b)$. In exercise segment also includes unbounded segments.

Comment: I think you mean exercise 2.29.

Comment: @MayureshL I have my copy of Rudin open and I don't see a definition of segment in chapter 2 that includes unbounded segments. Are you assuming he is including them because the exercise is false otherwise or is there something in the text that hints at that?

Comment: I am assuming he is including them because the exercise is false otherwise.

Comment: @JohnDouma Yes, that is my main complaint. He does not make it explicit in definition 2.17 that $a$ and $b$ can be part of the extended real numbers.

Comment: @JohnDouma I have written my thoughts on this in the answer.

Comment: I wonder why someone downvoted this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Walter Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* (third edition, 1976):

Pages 11-12:

> **1.23 Definition** The extended real number system consists of the real field $R$ and two symbols, $+\infty$ and $-\infty$. [...]

Page 31:

> **2.17 Definition** By the *segment* $(a, b)$ we mean the set of all real numbers $x$ such that $a < x < b$.
>
> By the *interval* $[a, b]$ we mean the set of all real numbers $x$ such that $a \leq x \leq b$. [...]

It is clear enough, I think, although not made explicit, that in this definition $a$ may be $-\infty$ and $b$ may be $+\infty$.

Page 33:

> **2.21 Examples** Let us consider the following subsets of $R^2$:
>   $$
> \begin{array}{cc}
> [\ldots] \\
> (g) & \text{The segment } (a, b).
> \end{array}
> $$ Let us note that *(d), (e), (g)* can be regarded also as subsets of $R^1$. Some properties of these sets are tabulated below:
>   $$
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
> {}  &  Closed   & Open &  Perfect  &  Bounded   \\
> [\ldots] \\
> (g) & \text{No} &  {}  & \text{No} & \text{Yes}
> \end{array}
> $$

Here it is undeniable, although again not explicit, that $a, b$ must both be real numbers, i.e. they cannot be $\pm\infty$.

So Rudin is at least a little inconsistent in his use of the term *segment*.

Because of this very inconsistency, it would be an overstatement to say that Exercise 2.29 is *false* as it stands. That would be to insist upon one of two possible interpretations of *segment*. The exercise is merely ambiguous; and common sense must be used to resolve the ambiguity.  Almost all indications are that "segments" may be unbounded. One of these indications, of course, is that it is the only interpretation that makes the exercise true.

For what it's worth, it seems most likely to me that **2.21** *(g)* was an isolated oversight, but I haven't checked the whole book to see if Rudin uses *segment* consistently everywhere else!

Comment: I do not have this book and have not read it but it seems to me that this portion of it could use a little modifying to ensure the clarity for the student.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at line no. 12, 13, 14 of page 12 in Rudin’s PMA.

With thsese lines in mind, we can allow $a$ and $b$ to take values $+\infty, -\infty$ (unless it’s mentioned that $a$ and $b$ are finite).

Comment: The pages to which you refer seem to be talking about the extended real number system. In the definition of segments, he explicitly mentions the real numbers.

Comment: No! In the definition of segment, $x$ is real number. There is no condition on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: You are correct. He says nothing about $a$ and $b$ except that they can be compared to $x$ with inequality.

Comment: But in part (g) of Example 2.21 on page 33 (third edition, as usual), Rudin describes the "segment" $(a, b)$ (with $a, b$ not explicitly specified as finite) as "bounded" (when identified with a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$). This suggests to me that the OP is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In Rudin's book, "closed sets" are defined as sets which contain all their limit points. "Open sets" are defined as sets all of whose points are interior points. So, in the metric space $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb R$ itself is both a closed and open set. It contains all its limits points, since any such limit points must be in the metric space, $\mathbb R$ itself. That it is an open set is clear. Either he allows $a,b$ to be extended real numbers, or otherwise I think it is also possible that when Rudin says "open" subset, he means "open **and not closed**" subset. This would resolve your issue.

Comment: No, since $(0,+\infty)$ still exists.